# PHP, AJAX Unable to display values based on dropdownlist

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, drop-down-menu

My codes were taken from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp, however i modified to better suit me, but it isn't working as it should be.

**Afile.php**

```
<head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getDescription.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <?php
                $comCtrl = new company_controller();
                $companyArray = $comCtrl->retrieveAllCompany();
                foreach($companyArray as $com) {
                    echo "<option value ='".$com."' >".$com."</option>";
                }//end foreach
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
```

**getDescription.php**

```
<?php

require_once('dbManager.php');


  $q = intval($_GET['q']);

  $dbMgr = new dbManager();
  $conn = $dbMgr->getDBConnection();      
  $query = "select company_address from company where company_name = '$q'";

  $result = mysql_query($query);


  echo "<table border='1'>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['company_address'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  $dbMgr->closeDBConnection($conn);
?>
```

**dbManager.php**

```
<?php
//require('/config/config.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '\..\config\config.php');
class dbManager{

    function getDBConnection(){
        // start connection
        $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        if (!$connect) 
        {
            die( 'Could not connect: '.mysql_error() );
        }

        // Select the database
        if(!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)) 
        {
            die('The database - '. DB_NAME .' does not exist!');
        }
        return $connect;
    }
    function closeDBConnection($connect){
        // close the connection
        mysql_close($connect);
    }
}
?>
```

I was expecting to have the same result as shown on the website. 
Instead, when i first run the files, i would see a dropdownlist(ddl) with all the company values, and beneath that ddl is the text "person info will be listed here". When i click on the ddl, i was hoping for the company's address to be populated at the div place of the text, but instead another ddl appeared beneath the first ddl. So now i have a ddl on the first row, another ddl on the second row, and the same text "person info will be listed here". WHat am i missing?

Comment: `"select company_address from company where company_name = '".$q."'";` this can be written as following: `"select company_address from company where company_name = '$q'`;

Comment: in the example site it is using mysqli and here you are using mysql..by the way mysql is deprated and its not safe

Comment: are you not getting any output or getting unexpected output

Comment: would that affect the results? i'm not getting expected output. When i first run the page, i should see a drop down list of all the companies, and beneath that DDL would be a text saying that "person info would be here". I managed to get that when i view the page. However, when i select a company value, the company's address should be displayed at the text with "person info will be listed here", but instead, another DDL appeared.

Comment: but dbconnection syntax are different for both so in confusion you might have done something wrong

Comment: ive been using this dbconnection method for other functions of my project and its working perfectly fine, so i dont think it has anything to do with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `mysqli_query()` or `PDO::query()`

This is the required syntax for `mysql_query()`

```
mysql_query(query,$conn);
```

**use:**

```
$q = trim($_GET['q']);
```